# Mongoid query only when field exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a news collection with documents, which may (or may not) have limited time of activity.

I have 3 fields which indicate if news is valid.  active, valid_from, valid_to. Normally I would do this kind of query:

where active = true and (valid_from = null or valid_from < Time.now) and (valid_to = null or valid_to > Time.now). OK. Time.now is ruby only, but I hope you understand.

Can this be done with Mongoid and how?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can try something like:

```
Model.where(active: true)
     .any_of({valid_from: nil}, {:valid_from.lt => Time.now})
     .any_of({valid_to: nil}, {:valid_to.gt => Time.now})
```

Comment: Close. But generated query looks like this:
"$or"=>[{"valid_from"=>nil},{"valid_from"=>{"$lt"=>2014-03-05 10:45:15 UTC}}, {"valid_to"=>nil}, {"valid_to"=>{"$gt"=>2014-03-05 10:45:15 UTC}}]}

Comment: Ups. Still learning editor:  

Close. But generated query looks like this:  

"$or"=>[{"valid_from"=>nil},{"valid_from"=>{"$lt"=>2014-03-05 10:45:15 UTC}}, {"valid_to"=>nil}, {"valid_to"=>{"$gt"=>2014-03-05 10:45:15 UTC}}]  
  
Which is wrong. It should probably be like this:  
  
"$or"=>[{"valid_from"=>nil},{"valid_from"=>{"$lt"=>2014-03-05 10:45:15 UTC}}],  
"$or"=>[ {"valid_to"=>nil}, {"valid_to"=>{"$gt"=>2014-03-05 10:45:15 UTC}}]    

by  
TheR

Comment: Thanks for showing the way. This code works as expected.  

Model.where(active: true)  
.and({"$or" => [{:valid_from => nil}, {:valid_from.lt => Time.now}]}, {"$or" => [{:valid_to => nil}, {:valid_to.gt => Time.now}]})


by
TheR